# How do I get rid of the reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I get this message at the start of my spring-webflux application.  How do I get rid of it?

```
DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
```

I am not sure what configuration I have to do.  I already pass in the environment variable and I don't have any overrides for `reactor`

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT=error
```

but it still shows up.

The statement is called from `Loggers` static initializer.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ? I'm running the same errors

Answer (score 0):

If you use logback, you can rid it off if you have `logback.xml` file with with root level info or reactor.util.Loggers level info. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <root level="info"/>
</configuration>
```

It must be `logback.xml` not `logback-spring.xml`, because the latter is ignored  when reactor logs own state before Spring context has started